# Using MongoDB.Driver inside azure functions

Tags: c#, .net, azure, .net-core, azure-functions

I'm trying to use an azure function to upload data to a mongodb but I get an error saying "The type or namespace name 'MongoDB' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)". I have a function.proj file that has refs to the MongoDB.Driver package but that doesn't seem to be working. I tried using the #r sytax to import the package but thats not working either. I'm using version 3 of the azure funtion runtime. Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Contents of the function.proj file

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="MongoDB.Driver.Core" Version="2.11.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="MongoDB.Driver" Version="2.11.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="MongoDB.Bson" Version="2.11.3" />
    <_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>true</_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>
</ItemGroup>
```

Using directives

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"

using System.Net;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using MongoDB.Bson;
```

Comment: @Liam better now?

Comment: What is the version of your funcion app?

Comment: The runtime version is 3

Comment: If you are based on v2 or v3, then function.proj should work. The reason why it sdon't work maybe the package is not support for C# script.

Comment: Would I need to switch to using the sdk and switch from c# script to normal c#?

Comment: When a package is available in C#-based functions, sometimes it may not be available in C# Script-based functions.

Comment: If you originally used C# for development, I suggest that you still use ordinary C#. After converting to C# script, the package may not be available.

Comment: Is there anyway to see what packages work with c# script?

Comment: As you can see from all these questions we need a [mcve]. There isn't enough information here

Comment: @Liam it's an azure function just add a function.proj file with the code above and add the using directives in the run csx file. Do you need help setting up an azure account?

Comment: Hi, I think you can not use C# script to do this, just install the 'MongoDB.Driver' will make the function service broken.

Comment: @Liam He had already give the needed, but what he want can not achieve.

Comment: @BowmanZhu thanks for the help. I'm going to try and upload the mongodb.driver.dll using kuda and if that doesn't work move away from csx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

Thanks for Ggd Hhdhd's working. Azure function can not install some package on azure when based on crx. The solution is to send related dll directly to the bin directory on azure. This is the doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp#referencing-custom-assemblies

And this is the structure:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp#folder-structure

**Original Answer:**

Please don't use C# script to do this.

Some package is not supported to install in C# script azure function on azure. I notice you install three package, but in fact, you just need to install MongoDB.Driver is ok. MongoDB.Driver is an integrated package that includes MongoDB.Driver.Core and MongoDB.Bson.

Problem is not from your code. The problem comes from just install the MongoDB.Driver package will broken the function.

By the way, the format of the function.proj should be like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="MongoDB.Driver" Version="2.11.3" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

You miss the `</Project>`.

I try to find some package but didn't find.